# Is a directed graph different from a flow graph?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I'm trying to understand directed graphs in a more applied way, especially in the context of the dataflow programming paradigm. Is the following flow chart a directed graph?

[image: (B.R. Sutherland (1966). "The On-line Graphical Specification of Computer Procedures". MIT)]

Is a directed graph essentially a flow diagram? Or is a flow diagram a type of directed graph?

---

I have made a change to my question based on comments from users and additional reading. I believe the example I have shown is called a [Flow Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_graph_(mathematics)). Is that correct?

So now my question is: Is a flow graph a type of directed graph?

Comment: A directed graph is a very precise mathematical object (actually, people might mean a few slightly different things by "directed graph", but each of those things has a very precise definition). Do you mean anything precise by "flow diagram"? It's easy to highlight similarities and/or differences between two precise definitions, but less easy to say what the differences might be between something precise and something ambiguous.

Comment: By flow diagram I mean something like a flowchart https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart. The problem I have is that a dataflow program is structured as a directed graph, such that a function or instruction can't execute until it has the data it needs. Essentially I want to know if my example diagram qualifies as a directed graph, or is it more akin to a flowchart.

Answer (score 0):

A *directed graph* like any mathematical object, is a *well-defined* object. It has a definition, so that handed any other mathematical object $X$, we can say whether or not $X$ is an example of a graph.

But what is the definition of a *flow chart*? Until you give a precise definition of *flow chart*, it's not a mathematical object and it's impossible to say how it compares to a directed graph. Furthermore, there isn't necessarily a correct definition of a flow chart; you get to define a flow chart however you need, depending on what you're thinking about. For example do you need to flow chart to "terminate," where flowing throw the chart you hit a terminal vertex? or can you have loops in your flow chart?

Comment: I think I may have found my answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_graph_(mathematics). Perhaps my question is then: Is a Flow graph a type of directed graph?

Comment: A flow graph (in the sense of the linked wikipedia page) is a directed graph with additional information (numerical labels on the edges, and perhaps more). However, I don't think this is the concept you really mean to refer to; perhaps you're looking for something more specific like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-flow_graph?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I think you are right. There appears to be a heirarchy: Directed graphs --> Flow graphs --> Signal-flow graphs. With the latter two being specific forms of a Directed graph?